# Why does different axis in power bi diagram affect calculation

Tags: filter, powerbi, calculation

I have a line diagram with ISO-Week number on the x-axis and pct on the y-axis as seen in this picture:

[image: Line diagram]

For the x-axis I have two different columns selected so that I can swap between showing the data for ISO-week or by Name of month:

[image: Data columns for x-axis]

As you can see in the first picture there is a spike in the orange data line at week 39. To me the filter context is clear, it's only calculated based on ISO-week since I haven't drilled down into the hierarchy of the x-axis. 
however if I switch places of the x-axis data columns in the right panel to this:

[image: Changed place of data columns for x-axis]

and I step down one step in the visual using this button:

[image: Circled button]

so that I am once again only looking at ISO-week number, the spike in the orange line at week 39 is now gone:

[image: Data lines no spike]

Getting different results depending on the order the different data columns have been added to the visual when only using one of them seems, to me, more like a bug rather than something to do with the filter context.

Or what is it this time I haven't grasped when it comes to filter context??

EDIT 1:

I've attached a bowdlerised version of the pbix-file. The three diagrams shows the three cases:

Top: ISOWeek and Name of month in x-axis field which results in the spike

Middle: Name of month and ISOWeek in x-axis field, view stepped down to ISOWeek which results in no spike

Bottom: Only ISOWeek in x-axis field which results in no spike.

[pbix file](https://www.fotooscar.se/download/StackOverflow.pbix)

I know that by removing the visual filter on the top diagram (Data Line 1 > -100%) removes this effect, though removing the filter doesn't explain the effect.

Comment: That's interesting. Difficult to diagnose without being able to reproduce it though. Can you share the .pbix file?

Comment: @alexis-olson New here so not sure you were notified that I uploaded a pbix-file. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that October 1 is in week 39 of 2017 but not in week 39 of 2018, so you're getting a -100% YoY change from the group ISOWeek 39 & October, which you're filtering out via the visual level filter on you measure' values.

Comment: I know by removing this visual filter, as I also wrote, it removes the effect. But this still doesn't, at least to me, explain why the spike shows up when I have Week over Month and not vice versa.
To me, if I'm not using the axis column it should not affect the calculation context, or what am I missing?

Comment: The visual level filter applies at the lowest level, even if that's not the level you're currently drilled down to. If this were not the case, the visual would not be consistent between levels.

Comment: Ok, so let me get this straight. "lowest level" applies to the column in the bottom of the list, not lowest resolution? Since I get different results if Week number is above Month compared to the other way around. 
"the visual would not be consistent between levels" well isn't this the opposite effect? 
To sum: if I add a second column as an axis in the visual though do not use it, it can still affect the graphical outcome, depending on where it is in the list of available choices for axis resolution? This seems very strange to me...

Comment: Yes, the lowest level which has the highest resolution. The visual is consistent when drilling up an down with a set hierarchy. If you alter the hierarchy of levels, then it is not necessarily going to match other hierarchies (nor would I expect it to). The visual's output is defined by all fields you've chosen to add even if they aren't currently visible. If you don't want to use a field, don't add it. If you do add it, the output needs to remain consistent when drilling up and down rather than deleting fields that are not currently visible.

Comment: I think I have a better understaning of pbi now, thanks! And thanks for sticking with me through my confusions.
Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the solution and/or voting if you feel your question has been resolved.